# Dash Plotly triggering callbacks

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a live-updating graph that connects to an SQL database. On page loading, the user inputs credentials and the appropriate data is loaded and displayed. I noticed that the lag time to load the data is related to the "dcc.interval" interval setting. This timer triggers the callback. However, when I added a "submit" button, to the callback input this does not trigger the callback, instead the callback awaits the "Interval" time before firing. My Question is: How can I get the callback to fire on button "submit" and not on 'interval' time on initial load?

```
dcc.Interval(
                    id='graph-update2',
                    interval=60000,
                    n_intervals=0),
```

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update-BP', 'n_intervals')],
    Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('data_list', 'data'),
)
def update_graph_scatter_1(n,submit, data_list):
    if data_list == 'null' or data_list is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    else: ....
```

Comment: Is that actually what your callback looks like? It's constructed incorrectly, because it has 3 inputs, and only 2 args. Can you share the fixed code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The update_graph_scatter_1 has 3 args (n, submit, data_list) corresponding to the 3 inputs (graph-update-BP, submit-val, data_list). The code is correct and runs without errors.

Comment: I see, I had misread the `n,submit` as `n_submit`.

Comment: The closing bracket for the `Inputs` is not enclosing all 3, though, just the first input. Does it change at all if you wrap all 3 inputs in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to make any difference but I appreciate the help. Perhaps I'll try to trigger a callback by outputting a button click to a N_interval?

Comment: Not sure whether that would work. If you remove the interval input, does the callback work correctly just using the button as a trigger? Also, if you can provide a minimal working example, I could try running it on my end to see what else I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'State' instead 'Input'. Inputs will trigger your callback; State do not. If
you need the the current “value” - aka State - of other dash components within
your callback, you pass them along via State.

```
           from dash.dependencies import Output,Input, State
          
           @app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
                        [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')],
                        [State('graph-update-BP', 'n_intervals'),
                         State('data_list', 'data')]
                        )
           def update_graph_scatter_1(n_clicks, graph-update-BP, data_list):
                if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
                   connection = cx.connect() #database connector
                   sql = '''''' #SQL Query
```